# Difficulties catching gateway timeouts in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, nginx

I have a big error class that hooks into [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), [`set_exception_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php), and even [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) (to run [`error_get_last()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php)) in order to catch every possible error. This is all important because this is for an API which **MUST** only ever output JSON, thus the error class intercepts all of PHP's errors and adds them to the response JSON.

However, for some reason I am still receiving the standard non-JSON response when there is a gateway timeout. In this case the timeout is being caused by MySQL taking to long to respond (>60 Seconds).

It is possible that the error is somehow being passed back to Nginx, however I am unsure how to confirm if that is what's happening.

**My Question:** How can I catch gateway timeouts in PHP?

---

**What I can confirm:**

- The syntax is all correct.
- The API responds normally if the query executes in time.
- PHP fatal errors, exceptions, and other errors are all being caught correctly within the same file as the query is being run.

**The environment:**

**OS:** Fedora 27
**PHP:** PHP-FPM running PHP 7.2
**Webserver:** Nginx 1.12.1
**Database:** MySQL 5.6.27

Comment: Hi Nicholas. Readers know to ask for new information, so there is no need for all 15M questions on this site to include a note asking if further information is required. We try to keep questions succinct here. If you would like to insist on your version, I suggest you flag for a moderator.

Comment: (As an aside, there is generally no need to start a post with "So". It's a conversational device popular with teenagers, indicating the existence of some unspoken context, but it's a bit chatty, and it doesn't actually add any meaning to a post. I edit it here not only for readability, but to suggest that written material does not need this at all, in the same way it does not need to start with "um", "ah" or "well").

Comment: Your "comment" belongs in the edit summery, it is not relevant here. Also you should add parenthesis that encase your entire comment to that list of things that are unnecessary.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your latest remark, and happy to hear further explanations as you wish. Was it just that you would like me to delete them after you have read them? Anyway, thank you for accepting the main part of my edit. Have a good day/evening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You can't do it in PHP.

Long answer: You *shouldn't* do it in PHP. This goes for any back-end system. The only reliable way of delivering JSON is by having your Nginx server handle it. If your back-end is trashed, like the server's overloaded, out of disk space, or is under extreme load, there's no way you can write any PHP code to fix this. It won't run. It can't run.

This means altering the Nginx configuration to have a JSON-based error document that can be emitted should your script take too long.

You can do this with custom `error_page` directives.

Another thing to consider is opening up the window on how long Nginx will wait for PHP to respond so it doesn't get impatient and terminate your request prematurely.

Depending on how you're dispatching these calls you'll need to adjust `fastcgi_read_timeout` or `proxy_read_timeout`. There's others like `proxy_connect_timeout` and `proxy_send_timeout` relating to trying to forward the request to PHP as well as `client_header_timeout` and `client_body_timeout` which occur when the client itself stalls before finishing the request.

Comment: If PHP is unable to finish running that is one thing, however this isn't the server running out of resources, this is the server refusing to continue handling a resource due to another resource's time limit. The is no reason why PHP shouldn't be able to shutdown gracefully.

Comment: That's why I'm saying more specifically that you "shouldn't", not that you can't. You can go through the trouble of trying to wrangle a solution in PHP here that will, with some luck, catch most of your error conditions, but the best bet is to do it at the Nginx level where you have final say. PHP *might* be able to recover, Nginx will *always* be able to handle it. Unless Nginx times out after your PHP code does, Nginx will get impatient and error out prematurely.

Comment: Well... you may have just actually answered the original question. For some reason it didn't even occur to me to check Nginx's timeout settings.

Comment: If you do handle it in PHP, that's fine, but keep in mind that PHP might not be able to, so having a fall-back `error_page` is not a bad idea. Your PHP code might be able to make a more informative JSON document while Nginx has to produce something that's fairly static.

Comment: I understand that, and generally speaking I agree with it. However, the bigger picture that wasn't mentioned in this case is that PHP is doing a lot more than just translating it to JSON. It is also logging the error along with all of the environment variables, backtraces, and user information to the filesystem and a database. This allows us to analyse, track, and get notifications about errors as they happen. Very little of this information is preserved in the Nginx log, thus it works out a lot better for us if PHP handles the errors.

Comment: That's true, though I try and engineer things to work under the most trying of circumstances. Nginx can be configured to log a lot more than it does by default, for example. Let's say 99% of your errors can be handled by PHP directly. Is that remaining 1% important to you? This is where fail-safes come into play, where under the most severe strain your Nginx *still* produces JSON. Tools like [Airbrake](https://airbrake.io/languages) can handle the 99%, the remainder's usually something you want outage alerts for.

Comment: This issue was ultimately fixed by increasing the following Nginx configs: `client_header_timeout`, `client_body_timeout`, and `fastcgi_read_timeout`. If you modify your answer to include this information I will accept it as the official answer.

Comment: @NicholasSummers Added that and a few others you might consider.